# Multi-line javascript throwing error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a block of HTML using javascript. To keep my code clean I am trying to put the code on separate lines. It is giving me an error saying that there is an incorrect `<` character, but I never closed out the string. Here is my code, please help! Thanks!

```
var form = jQuery('
<div id="link">
    <div id="link-options">
        <p class="howto">Add a quote to the page</p>
        <div>
            <label><span>Text<br/></span><textarea name="text" id="text"></textarea></label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label><span>Person</span><input type="text" name="person"></label>\
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="submitbox">
        <div id="update">
            <input type="button" id="quote-submit" class="button-primary" value="Insert Shortcode" name="submit" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you are technically not closing the string, there are new lines within your string. Javascript will interpret the new lines as a close string character. Because it is closing the string, you are getting the error. Try adding an escape to the end of the lines to escape the line break:

```
var form = jQuery('\
<div id="link">\
    <div id="link-options">\
        <p class="howto">Add a quote to the page</p>\
        <div>\
            <label><span>Text<br/></span><textarea name="text" id="text"></textarea></label>\
        </div>\
        <div>\
            <label><span>Person</span><input type="text" name="person"></label>\
        </div>\
    </div>\
    <div class="submitbox">\
        <div id="update">\
            <input type="button" id="quote-submit" class="button-primary" value="Insert Shortcode" name="submit" />\
        </div>\
    </div>\
</div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

When doing multiline variables in js I like to use the join() function.

```
var form = [
  '<div>',
    '<p>blah blah</p>',
  '<div>'
].join('\n');
```

Answer (score 0):

i like to do [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/String_Operators):

```
var form = jQuery(
    '<div id="link">' +
        '<div id="link_options">'  +
            '<p class="howto">how to add a quote to the page</p>' +
        '</div>' +
    '</div>'
);
```